# Build hierarchical multidimensional array with all year, month, day, and hour values within a range of years

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, hierarchical-data, date-range

I am trying to create a multidimensional array for Years, Months, Days, Hours so I can track certain data on an hourly basis. I am attempting to initialize this array through nested for loops but seem to be failing miserably at it.

```
$Year = array();

//This starts in 2015 and works until 2018
for($z=0; $z < 3; ++$z)
{
    $Month = array();
    array_push($Year, $Month);

    //Months
    for($a=0; $a < 12; ++$a)
    {
        //Days
        for($b=0; $b < GetDaysInMonth($a); ++$b)
        {
            $Day = array();
            array_push($Month, $Day);

            //Hours
            for($c = 0; $c < 24; ++$c)
            {
                $Hours = array(0);
                array_push($Day, $Hours);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The goal is to initialize an array of size 24 for hours, push that into an array for days, push the days array into months and the months array into years. Every time I try to access the data it seems to not exist however. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you attempting to access array elements? Since you are populating arrays using `array_push()`, all your arrays will be numerically indexed beginning with index 0. You are also using prefix increments (e.g. `++$a`) in your `for` loops, so they may be executing 1 less time than you expect. You may want to change to suffix increments (e.g. `$a++`). So for example, your `$Year` variable likely has only 2 values, indexed as `0` and `1` respectively, rather than years. Use `print_r()` to dump the contents of the arrays and see what's actually in them.

Comment: [Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use `$array[] =` because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Comment: Thanks for the print_r() feedback. I didn't know about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must `array_push` after each `for`

```
$Years = array();
//This starts in 2015 and works until 2018
for($z=0; $z < 3; $z++) {
    $Year = array();
    //Months
    for($a=0; $a < 12; $a++) {
        $Month = array();
        //Days
        for($b=0; $b < GetDaysInMonth($a); $b++) {
            $Day = array();
            //Hours
            for($c = 0; $c < 24; $c++) {
                $Hours = $c;
                array_push($Day, $Hours); // push Hours into Day
            }
            array_push($Month, $Day); // push Days into Month
        }
        array_push($Year, $Month); // push Months into Year
    }
    array_push($Years, $Year); // push each Year in a var with all Years
}
```

Edit: I added a variable named `$Years` to store all the years

Answer (score 0):

From the start of 2015 through all of 2018, expect 35,064 elements in the deepest level.  This is a rather chunky consumption of memory, you may need to boost your memory limit or change your strategy.

As for generating this multidimensional array with indexed levels, you can use the following: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dP742))

```
$start = 2015;
$end = 2018;
$years = [];
foreach (range($start, $end) as $y) {
    $months = [];
    for ($m = 1; $m <= 12; ++$m) {
        $lastDayOfMonth = date('t', strtotime("$y-$m-01"));
        $days = [];
        for ($d = 1; $d <= $lastDayOfMonth; ++$d) {
            $days[] = range(0, 23);
        }
        $months[] = $days;
    }
    $years[] = $months;
}
var_export($years);
```

---

If this was my task, I'd probably work with more intuitive keys on all levels and leverage datetime objects and loop over a datetime period. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/R2EYF))

```
$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('2015-01-01'),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    new DateTime('2018-12-31'),
    DatePeriod::INCLUDE_END_DATE
);

$years = [];
foreach ($period as $date) {
    $years[$date->format('Y')][$date->format('m')][$date->format('d')] = range(0, 23);
}
var_export($years);
```