# Creating an array from a input from text file having 4 columns

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I stuck with problem of creating one array of 4 different arrays.
I need one array with values to create graph of it... Now I'm getting 4 arrays with string.
The data is 4 column with Time, ax ay az position and header. I'm removing header and names of the columns first. The data looks like:

ID_PATIENT, ID_MOVE, NAME, SURNAME

TIME    aX  aY  aZ
713 -620    -2228   15832
755 -596    -2204   15804
797 -596    -2176   15876
838 -584    -2072   15808
880 -484    -2224   15988
921 -676    -2180   15892
963 -532    -2128   15944

Here you have sample of my code, which parsing data from .txt file:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    echo $_POST['name'];

    $filee= $_POST['name'];

    echo "<br>";

$file =  "data/".$filee;


$Time=array();
$aX=array();
$aY=array();
$aZ=array();

    $lines = file($file);


    for($i=0; $i<2; ++$i) {
    $which=$i;
    unset($lines[$which--]); 
    $filee=fopen($lines,'w');  
    fwrite($filee,join('',$lines));
    fclose($filee);  
    }

foreach($lines as $line)
{
list( $Timetmp, $aXtmp, $aYtmp, $aZtmp) = split("\t", $line );
array_push($Time, $Timetmp);
array_push($aX, $aXtmp);
array_push($aY, $aYtmp);
array_push($aZ,$aZtmp);
}

foreach($Time as $indice => $valor)
print "$valor <br>";

echo "....<BR>";

foreach($aX as $indice => $valor)
print "$valor <br>";

echo "....<BR>";

foreach($aY as $indice => $valor)
print "$valor <br>";

 echo "....<BR>";


foreach($aZ as $indice => $valor)
print "$valor <br>"; 


 ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multidimensional Array - PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792156/multidimensional-array-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an **associative array for a better representation of your data** :

In your code you can do following modifications:

```
$processedArray = array();    
foreach($lines as $line)
    {
    list( $Timetmp, $aXtmp, $aYtmp, $aZtmp) = split("\t", $line );
    $processedArray[] = array("time"=>$Timetmp,"ax"=>$aXtmp,"ay"=>$aYtmp,"az"=>$aZtmp);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
array(
      array("time"=>713,"ax"=>-620,"ay"=>-2228,"az"=>15832),
      array("time"=>755,"ax"=>-596,"ay"=>-2204,"az"=>15804),
      ....,
      ....
)
```